# Commons.js not generated

Tags: gatsby

I cannot start the default Gatsby project. I have these errors in Chrome after I do 'gatsby develop':

1. GET http://localhost:8000/commons.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2. Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/commons.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

gatsby 2.4.1, node 8.11.3

How to start the default Gatsby project?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact issue recently. I was able to fix the issue by removing all spaces (or "%20"s) from the name of the folder I was running my Gatsby project from. Hope this helps.